# C++ write part of *char buffer to temp file on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, io

I am pretty new to C++ and win32. I need to accomplish a pretty simple task:

1. I have a buffer char* buffer whose length I know and which holds some binary data. Can you please provide a sample code that will write the contents of that buffer (given starting index and length) to a temporary file (location must be writable even without admin rights) on Windows (win32 api)? So, to accomplish this I would have to know how to get a valid temp file name on windows to which I can write, and how should I rpoperly write to that file some binary data from a given portion of my char* buffer.
2. Also I cannot seem to figure out if it's ok to use char for binary files, but the problem is that ifstream by default will read data as char.
3. And just a quick side question: do I always have to delete any pointers once I am done with them. I.e. in my example above, would I have to call delete buffer once I am done with it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific problems are you having?  StackOverflow isn't a tutorial site.  (Though #2 and #3 are easy enough to answer: Yes and Yes)

Comment: You ask about different things, I suppose, in the first question you address windows api, in the second you talk about ifstream problem. What API do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a buffer char* buffer whose length I know and which holds some binary data. Can you please provide a sample code that will write
>   the contents of that buffer (given starting index and length) to a
>   temporary file (location must be writable even without admin rights)
>   on Windows (win32 api)?

A quick search in google returns the document from the manufacturer about temporary files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363875(v=vs.85).aspx

Remember that, once you use temporary files this way, your code is automatically not portable (in case this is important to you).

The code you are asking for, once you have a name and a directory for your temporary file,is trivial. Again, a quick search in google returns:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21018/

If you prefer to adhere to the C (old) style instead of using IOStream, you instead can also use:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/

> And just a quick side question: do I always have to delete any pointers once I am done with them. I.e. in my example above, would I
>   have to call delete buffer once I am done with it?

You have to always delete the allocated memory, pointed by a pointer (that's the origin of its name), after using it.

```
char * buffer = new char[MaxBuffer];

// more things ...

delete[] buffer;
```

Remember to use `delete[]` when deleting vectors instead of single objects.